# request for member 'compareTo' in charArrayBuffer, which is of non-class type 'char[9]'

Tags: c++, compareto, arrays, arduino-uno

The idea was to create a code to compare a name read with serial.read, with a premade name.

Both declarations are char arrays, length [9], and therefor I don't understand why the problem occures.

Code:

```
char name1[9] = "Jesper";

char nameBuffer[9];

void setup()
{

      Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{

      int i = 0;

      nameBuffer[0] = 0;

      while(Serial.available() == 0)
        {
          // wait for data to be send
        }

        while(Serial.available() > 0)
        {   
          int inByte = Serial.read();
          delay(50);
          nameBuffer[i] = char(inByte);
          i++;
        }

      Serial.print("Searching for: "); 
      Serial.println(nameBuffer);

     if (nameBuffer.compareTo(name1) < 0 )
     {
       Serial.println("Did you mean to write: \"Jesper\"");
     }
     else
     {
       Serial.println("Jesper found");
     }  
    }
```

Error recieved:

error: request for member 'compareTo' in 'nameBuffer', which is of non-class type 'char[9]'

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (nameBuffer.compareTo(name1) < 0 )
```

with

```
if (strcmp(nameBuffer, name1) != 0 )
```

as `nameBuffer` cannot be accessed with a `.` operator.

BTW, according to the error message, you are programming in C++, not in C.

Comment: Sorry about that, I might've found a string comparing guide that included c++, but I'm learning to type in the language c. 
So . operator is a tool in c++ ??
Your answer worked perfect too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
strncmp(nameBuffer, name1, sizeof nameBuffer) < 0
```

instead of

```
nameBuffer.compareTo(name1) < 0
```

your variables are `char` arrays the are not `class`es so they have no methods.

I use `strncmp` because I cant be sure that `nameBuffer` and `name1` are properly null terminated, So this way you prevent some problems if they weren't

Since you are using c++, you can also try using `std::string` instead, since that way you wont need to worry about the length of the strings if you declare

```
std::string nameBuffer;
std::string name1("Jasper");
```

then to append the `char`s you can just

```
nameBuferr += static_cast<char>(inByte);
```

and to do the comparison just

```
if (nameBuffer < name1)
```

Comment: If i add the argument  sizeof nameBuffer so that:  
strncmp(nameBuffer, name1, sizeof nameBuffer) < 0

I get following error: too many arguments to function int strcmp(const char*, const char*)

Comment: `strcmp` takes only two `'\0'` terminated strings, so your syntax is wrong, see the `n` after `str` it's `strncmp` <- `str{n}cmp`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line in the agreement for use, thanks for your help